# Android: Out of Memory on a 3240016-byte allocation

Tags: android

I'm always ending up facing with this issue. Went through a lot of questions on the same (viz. [this pdf](http://dl.google.com/googleio/2010/android-world-of-listview-android.pdf), [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11826446/out-of-memory-on-a-byte-allocation), [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836643/out-of-memory-error-on-byte-allocation) and so on). Since I'm still naive in Android, could anyone help me on this?

**Logcat:**

```
01-20 22:41:50.644: D/dalvikvm(4838): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed <1K, 14% free 55713K/64583K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
01-20 22:41:50.644: E/dalvikvm-heap(4838): Out of memory on a 3240016-byte allocation.
01-20 22:41:50.644: I/dalvikvm(4838): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
01-20 22:41:50.644: I/dalvikvm(4838):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40e11508 self=0x40d2e9a0
01-20 22:41:50.644: I/dalvikvm(4838):   | sysTid=4838 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1075126064
01-20 22:41:50.644: I/dalvikvm(4838):   | schedstat=( 3230609420 544631405 2986 ) utm=302 stm=21 core=0
01-20 22:41:50.644: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
01-20 22:41:50.649: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:623)
01-20 22:41:50.649: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:476)
01-20 22:41:50.649: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:781)
01-20 22:41:50.649: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1963)
01-20 22:41:50.649: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:672)
01-20 22:41:50.649: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:14480)
01-20 22:41:50.649: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at axaart.collectors.adapter.CustomListAdapter.getView(CustomListAdapter.java:82)
01-20 22:41:50.649: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2461)
01-20 22:41:50.649: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1775)
01-20 22:41:50.649: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:678)
01-20 22:41:50.649: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:739)
01-20 22:41:50.649: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1628)
01-20 22:41:50.649: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2296)
01-20 22:41:50.649: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
01-20 22:41:50.649: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
01-20 22:41:50.654: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
01-20 22:41:50.654: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
01-20 22:41:50.654: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
01-20 22:41:50.654: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
01-20 22:41:50.654: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
01-20 22:41:50.654: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
01-20 22:41:50.654: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
01-20 22:41:50.654: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
01-20 22:41:50.654: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1585)
01-20 22:41:50.654: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
01-20 22:41:50.654: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
01-20 22:41:50.654: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
01-20 22:41:50.654: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
01-20 22:41:50.654: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
01-20 22:41:50.654: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
01-20 22:41:50.654: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
01-20 22:41:50.654: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
01-20 22:41:50.654: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
01-20 22:41:50.654: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
01-20 22:41:50.654: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:948)
01-20 22:41:50.654: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
01-20 22:41:50.654: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
01-20 22:41:50.654: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
01-20 22:41:50.654: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
01-20 22:41:50.654: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
01-20 22:41:50.654: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
01-20 22:41:50.654: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
01-20 22:41:50.654: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
01-20 22:41:50.654: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
01-20 22:41:50.654: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
01-20 22:41:50.659: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
01-20 22:41:50.659: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
01-20 22:41:50.659: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
01-20 22:41:50.659: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1992)
01-20 22:41:50.659: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1813)
01-20 22:41:50.659: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1112)
01-20 22:41:50.659: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4472)
01-20 22:41:50.659: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
01-20 22:41:50.659: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
01-20 22:41:50.659: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
01-20 22:41:50.659: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
01-20 22:41:50.659: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-20 22:41:50.659: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-20 22:41:50.659: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-20 22:41:50.659: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
01-20 22:41:50.659: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-20 22:41:50.659: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-20 22:41:50.659: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
01-20 22:41:50.659: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
01-20 22:41:50.659: I/dalvikvm(4838):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-20 22:41:50.664: A/libc(4838): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 4838 (aart.collectors)
```

**CustomListAdapter.java**

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ItemDetailTO> {

    private List<ItemDetailTO> aList;
    private List<ItemDetailTO> orignalList;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ItemDetailTO info = null;
    private byte[] decodeStringImage;
    Bitmap decodedByteImage;
//  private TextView txtvwLocation;
//  private Context context;

    public CustomListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<ItemDetailTO> list) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, list);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
//      this.context = context;
        this.aList = list;
        this.orignalList = list;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
//      inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.common_list_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.holder, holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(R.id.holder);
        }
//      View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.common_list_item, parent, false);
        ListColor listColorInstance = new ListColor();
        
//      if(view == null) {
//          view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.common_list_item, parent, false);          
//      }
        
        listColorInstance.listcolorsetter(convertView, position);
        info  = aList.get(position);
        
        if(info != null) {
            holder.txtvwTitle.setText(info.getsTitle());
            holder.txtvwCategory.setText(info.getsCategory());
            
            if (info.getsCcy() != null) {
                holder.txtvwValue.setText(String.format("%.2f", info.getdValue()) + " " + info.getsCcy());
            } else {
                holder.txtvwValue.setText(String.format("%.2f", info.getdValue()));
            }
            
            if(info.getImage() != null) {
                decodeStringImage = Base64.decode(info.getImage(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                decodedByteImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodeStringImage, 0, decodeStringImage.length);
                holder.imgvwItemImage.setImageBitmap(decodedByteImage);
            } else {
                holder.imgvwItemImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image_placeholder); 
            }
        }
        
        if (decodedByteImage != null) {
            decodedByteImage = null;
            System.gc();
        }
        
//      return rowView;
        return convertView;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return aList.size();
    }
    
    public void resetData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        aList = orignalList;
    }
    
    private class ViewHolder {
        private ImageView imgvwItemImage;
        private TextView txtvwTitle;
        private TextView txtvwCategory;
        private TextView txtvwValue;
        
        public ViewHolder(View root) {
            imgvwItemImage = (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.imgvwItemImage);
            txtvwTitle = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.txtvwtitle);
            txtvwCategory = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.txtvwcategory);
            txtvwValue = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.txtvwvalue);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:**

This issue comes up when I'm trying to populate my listview in any multiple activities.

Answer (score 4):

You may try by adding this line to your manifest file. It will allocate the large memory for your application.

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

Answer (score 2):

Each bitmap which you use costs 4mb in memroy. You can use a resized bitmap by the following method.

```
private Bitmap decodeBitmap(int targetWidth, int targetHeight) throws IOException {
    final BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opts.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getAssets().open("frog.jpg"), null, opts);

    opts.inSampleSize = getBitmapSampleSize(opts, targetWidth, targetHeight);

    opts.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getAssets().open("frog.jpg"), null, opts);
}

private int getBitmapSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options opts, int targetWidth, int targetHeight) {
    final int width = opts.outWidth;
    final int height = opts.outHeight;
    Log.d("tag", "bitmap's size is " + width + ", " + height);
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > targetHeight || width > targetWidth) {
        if (width > height) {
            inSampleSize = (int) Math.floor((float)height / (float)targetHeight);
        } else {
            inSampleSize = (int) Math.floor((float)width / (float)targetWidth);
        }
    }
    Log.d("tag", "target size is " + targetWidth + ", " + targetHeight);
    Log.d("tag", "inSampleSize is " + inSampleSize);
    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Android has very strict limit of how much memory can a single application allocate for itself.  Even though there is memory available on the device it doesn't mean the OS will give it to you.   So you are pretty much out of luck.   Here are some things you can do:

1. Use more efficient data representation that doesn't require such large allocations.  Perhaps you could compress / pre-process data on the web service outside of your device.
2. If that's not an option,  you can build your own platform image and change the settings of memory limit per application.  [Look here for more information.](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html)
3. If (2) is not an option for you.  You can write a native lib which will hold the data for you.  The memory limit applies only to Java/Dalvik allocations.  Native code can do whatever it wants.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you please provide me a sample code for option 3 as per my scenario where I decode a base64 string into image and displaying the same in the imageview?

Answer (score 0):

```
decodedByteImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodeStringImage, 0, decodeStringImage.length);
```

imageloader is Recommended. 
https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader